# Issue in clear button on VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make calculator using Vb.net and facing two  issues.

1) I HAVE DONE THE CODING EVERYTHING IS WORKING FINE BUT ONLY WHEN I CLICK THE CLEAR BUTTON then +,-,/,= STOPS WORKING ...

2) the equal button is also not working when i am  adding or subtracting it gives wrong answer

```
public Class calcuTESTForm1
    Private isDotExixtsbool As Boolean
    Private isFirstnumbool As Boolean
    Private FirstNumDecimal As Boolean
    Private SecondNumberdecimal As Boolean
    Private oPeratorString As String


    Private Sub btnone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnone.Click
        RemoveZero(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btntwo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btntwo.Click
        RemoveZero(2)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnthree_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnthree.Click
        RemoveZero(3)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnfour_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfour.Click
        RemoveZero(4)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
        RemoveZero(5)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonsix_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonsix.Click
        RemoveZero(6)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnseven_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnseven.Click
        RemoveZero(7)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttoneight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttoneight.Click
        RemoveZero(8)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonNine_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNine.Click
        RemoveZero(9)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnzero_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnzero.Click
        RemoveZero(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonbot_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonbot.Click
        If isDotExixtsbool = False Then
            lblDisplay.Text &= "."
            isDotExixtsbool = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CalcuTESTform1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        isDotExixtsbool = False
        isFirstnumbool = False
    End Sub
    'Remove zero at the start of number

    Public Sub RemoveZero(ByVal number As Integer)
        If lblDisplay.Text = "0" Then
            lblDisplay.Text = number
        Else
            lblDisplay.Text &= number
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        lblDisplay.Text = ""
        lblDisplay.Text = 0
        isDotExixtsbool = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub minusandadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles minusandadd.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonplus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonplus.Click
        oPeratorString = "+"
        IsFirstNumberAvailable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles equalbutton.Click
        ' only do ,if first number is available 
        If isFirstnumbool Then
            secondNumberdecimal = CType(lblDisplay.Text, Decimal)
        End If
        Dim resultDecimal As Decimal

        Select Case oPeratorString
            Case Is = "+"
                resultDecimal = FirstNumDecimal + SecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "-"
                resultDecimal = FirstNumDecimal - SecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "/"
                resultDecimal = FirstNumDecimal / SecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "*"
                resultDecimal = FirstNumDecimal * SecondNumberdecimal
        End Select

        'now Calculate the Result
        'calculateResult(FirstNumDecimal, SecondNumberdecimal, oPeratorString, resultDecimal)
        'show the result in the textbox
        lblDisplay.Text = resultDecimal.ToString()

    End Sub
    Private Sub calculateResult(ByVal aFirstNumDecimal As Decimal,
                                ByVal aSecondNumberdecimal As Decimal,
                                ByVal aOperator As String,
                                ByRef aResult As String)
        MessageBox.Show(aFirstNumDecimal)
        Select Case aOperator
            Case Is = "+"
                aResult = aFirstNumDecimal + aSecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "-"
                aResult = aFirstNumDecimal - aSecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "/"
                aResult = aFirstNumDecimal / aSecondNumberdecimal
            Case Is = "*"
                aResult = aFirstNumDecimal * aSecondNumberdecimal
        End Select
    End Sub
    Public Sub IsFirstNumberAvailable()
        ' only do it, if first Num is not available 
        If isFirstnumbool = False Then
            ' Save the current number to firstNumDecimal
            firstNumDecimal = CType(lblDisplay.Text, Decimal)
            ' Make first  Num is available 
            isFirstnumbool = True
            ' Reset the  lblDisplay.Text to enter 2nd Number
            lblDisplay.Text = "0"

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonmlt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonmlt.Click
        oPeratorString = "*"
        IsFirstNumberAvailable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonmulty_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Buttonmulty.Click
        oPeratorString = "/"
        IsFirstNumberAvailable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonMnus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonMnus.Click
        oPeratorString = "-"
        IsFirstNumberAvailable()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If lblDisplay.Text < " " Then
            lblDisplay.Text = Mid(lblDisplay.Text, 1, Len(lblDisplay.Text) - 1 + 1)
        Else
            lblDisplay.Text = Mid(lblDisplay.Text, 1, Len(lblDisplay.Text) - 1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

_
Partial Class calcuTESTForm1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.btnclear = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnseven = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnfour = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btnone = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Btntwo = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Btnthree = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttonmulty = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.lblDisplay = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.btnzero = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.btn5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttonsix = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttoneight = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.ButtonNine = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttonbot = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.ButtonMnus = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttonplus = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Buttonmlt = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.equalbutton = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.minusandadd = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'btnclear
    '
    Me.btnclear.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    Me.btnclear.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btnclear.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(211, 270)
    Me.btnclear.Name = "btnclear"
    Me.btnclear.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btnclear.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btnclear.Text = "C"
    Me.btnclear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
    '
    'btnseven
    '
    Me.btnseven.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btnseven.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 175)
    Me.btnseven.Name = "btnseven"
    Me.btnseven.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btnseven.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btnseven.Text = "7"
    Me.btnseven.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnfour
    '
    Me.btnfour.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btnfour.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 128)
    Me.btnfour.Name = "btnfour"
    Me.btnfour.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btnfour.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btnfour.Text = "4"
    Me.btnfour.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btnone
    '
    Me.btnone.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btnone.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 81)
    Me.btnone.Name = "btnone"
    Me.btnone.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btnone.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btnone.Text = "1"
    Me.btnone.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Btntwo
    '
    Me.Btntwo.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Btntwo.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(78, 81)
    Me.Btntwo.Name = "Btntwo"
    Me.Btntwo.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Btntwo.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Btntwo.Text = "2"
    Me.Btntwo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Btnthree
    '
    Me.Btnthree.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Btnthree.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 81)
    Me.Btnthree.Name = "Btnthree"
    Me.Btnthree.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Btnthree.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Btnthree.Text = "3"
    Me.Btnthree.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttonmulty
    '
    Me.Buttonmulty.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttonmulty.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(211, 81)
    Me.Buttonmulty.Name = "Buttonmulty"
    Me.Buttonmulty.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttonmulty.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttonmulty.Text = "/"
    Me.Buttonmulty.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'lblDisplay
    '
    Me.lblDisplay.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Me.lblDisplay.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.lblDisplay.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 20)
    Me.lblDisplay.Name = "lblDisplay"
    Me.lblDisplay.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(249, 43)
    Me.lblDisplay.TabIndex = 1
    Me.lblDisplay.Text = "0"
    Me.lblDisplay.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    '
    'btnzero
    '
    Me.btnzero.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btnzero.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 222)
    Me.btnzero.Name = "btnzero"
    Me.btnzero.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btnzero.TabIndex = 2
    Me.btnzero.Text = "0"
    Me.btnzero.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'btn5
    '
    Me.btn5.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.btn5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(78, 128)
    Me.btn5.Name = "btn5"
    Me.btn5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.btn5.TabIndex = 0
    Me.btn5.Text = "5"
    Me.btn5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttonsix
    '
    Me.Buttonsix.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttonsix.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 128)
    Me.Buttonsix.Name = "Buttonsix"
    Me.Buttonsix.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttonsix.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttonsix.Text = "6"
    Me.Buttonsix.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttoneight
    '
    Me.Buttoneight.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttoneight.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(78, 175)
    Me.Buttoneight.Name = "Buttoneight"
    Me.Buttoneight.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttoneight.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttoneight.Text = "8"
    Me.Buttoneight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'ButtonNine
    '
    Me.ButtonNine.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.ButtonNine.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 175)
    Me.ButtonNine.Name = "ButtonNine"
    Me.ButtonNine.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.ButtonNine.TabIndex = 0
    Me.ButtonNine.Text = "9"
    Me.ButtonNine.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttonbot
    '
    Me.Buttonbot.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 25.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttonbot.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(78, 222)
    Me.Buttonbot.Name = "Buttonbot"
    Me.Buttonbot.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttonbot.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttonbot.Text = "."
    Me.Buttonbot.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'ButtonMnus
    '
    Me.ButtonMnus.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 25.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.ButtonMnus.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 222)
    Me.ButtonMnus.Name = "ButtonMnus"
    Me.ButtonMnus.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.ButtonMnus.TabIndex = 0
    Me.ButtonMnus.Text = "-"
    Me.ButtonMnus.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttonplus
    '
    Me.Buttonplus.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttonplus.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(211, 128)
    Me.Buttonplus.Name = "Buttonplus"
    Me.Buttonplus.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttonplus.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttonplus.Text = "+"
    Me.Buttonplus.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Buttonmlt
    '
    Me.Buttonmlt.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Buttonmlt.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(211, 175)
    Me.Buttonmlt.Name = "Buttonmlt"
    Me.Buttonmlt.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Buttonmlt.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Buttonmlt.Text = "*"
    Me.Buttonmlt.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'equalbutton
    '
    Me.equalbutton.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.equalbutton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(211, 223)
    Me.equalbutton.Name = "equalbutton"
    Me.equalbutton.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
    Me.equalbutton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.equalbutton.TabIndex = 3
    Me.equalbutton.Text = "="
    Me.equalbutton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button3
    '
    Me.Button3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(17, 269)
    Me.Button3.Name = "Button3"
    Me.Button3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Button3.TabIndex = 5
    Me.Button3.Text = "00"
    Me.Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'minusandadd
    '
    Me.minusandadd.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.minusandadd.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(139, 269)
    Me.minusandadd.Name = "minusandadd"
    Me.minusandadd.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.minusandadd.TabIndex = 0
    Me.minusandadd.Text = "-/+"
    Me.minusandadd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(78, 269)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 41)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 6
    Me.Button1.Text = "←"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'calcuTESTForm1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(277, 323)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button3)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.equalbutton)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnzero)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblDisplay)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttonmulty)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnclear)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.minusandadd)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.ButtonMnus)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttonbot)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttonmlt)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.ButtonNine)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttoneight)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttonplus)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Buttonsix)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btn5)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Btnthree)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Btntwo)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnone)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnfour)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnseven)
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.Name = "calcuTESTForm1"
    Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    Me.Text = "kevulator"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
Friend WithEvents btnclear As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btnseven As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btnfour As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btnone As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Btntwo As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Btnthree As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttonmulty As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents lblDisplay As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents btnzero As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents btn5 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttonsix As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttoneight As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents ButtonNine As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttonbot As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents ButtonMnus As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttonplus As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Buttonmlt As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents equalbutton As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Button3 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents minusandadd As System.Windows.Forms.Button
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

at first glance it looks like one of the errors is in this sub

```
        Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        lblDisplay.Text = ""
        lblDisplay.Text = 0
        isDotExixtsbool = True
        End Sub
```

If btn4 is not the name for your clear button, then the sub be something like

```
        Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclear.Click
        lblDisplay.Text = ""
        lblDisplay.Text = 0
        isDotExixtsbool = True
        End Sub
```

If you can provide codes from the designer (probably CalcuTESTform1.Designer.vb) then we can help you more.

Comment: You are very much welcome. Please feel free to edit your question (to add more information that will help us solve your problem on the other buttons and/or related click handlers).

Comment: In the above i have edit it and gave the full information CalcuTESTform1.Designer.vb

Comment: the codes from the designer (probably CalcuTESTform1.Designer.vb), or if you don't want that you can just give us the names of the buttons from your design view (so that we can check your problem on the +,-,/,= buttons)